# Возможно ли получить номер квартиры с помощью API Геосаджеста?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Пытаюсь реализовать выбор адреса юзера, все работает идеально, за исключением того что я не получаю в ответе номер квартиры, даже при ее вводе.
Это вообще возможно сделать с помощью геосаджеста?или нужно использовать что-то другое для этого?

Comment: Сейчас выбрать квартиру в Геосаджесте невозможно. Огромное количество квартир в выдаче мешало бы добавлять в выдачу другие дома. А в чём конкретно состоит задача? Почему номер квартиры нужно получать от геосаджеста, а не вводить отдельным полем?

Comment: Задача облегчить выбора адреса юзером, например у дадата есть возможность выбора квартиры и лимиты на бесплатный тарифы там побольше, так что я пока не очень понял преимущества яндекс геосайджеста